# Splitting a list of a-lists into sub-lists

Tags: list, common-lisp

For a hobby project I deal with lists of a-lists like

`((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 3) (0 . 4) (0 . 7) (0 . 8))`

where the list could have up to nine elements and the a-lists consists of just integers from `0` to `9`. I want to split the list into the sub-units with consecutive `cdr`s.

`(((0 . 0) (0 . 1)) ((0 . 3) (0 . 4)) ((0 . 7) (0 . 8)))`

A sub-unit can have just one element and the list can have no sub-unit at all, like:

`((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 2) (0 . 4))` or 
`((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 2) (0 . 3) (0 . 4))`

The results should be:

`(((0 . 0) (0 . 1)) ((0 . 3) (0 . 4)) ((0 . 7) (0 . 8)))`

`(((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 2)) ((0 . 4)))`

`(((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 2) (0 . 3) (0 . 4)))`

Using [iterate](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) I came up with a two-step approach. First, scan the list and check whether there are sub-units or not, returning the positions of the gaps. And second, split the list apart using a function `split-at` I implemented before:

```
(defun split-at (count original-list)
  (unless (or (null original-list) (minusp count)
              (>= count (length original-list)))
    (list (subseq original-list 0 count)
          (subseq original-list count))))

(defun sub-units (units)
  "Scan UNITS for sub-units."
  (iter
    (for (a . b) in units)
    (for last-b previous b initially -1)
    (for pos from 0)
    (unless (= 1 (- b last-b))
      (collecting pos))))

(defun split-sub-units (units)
  "Splits UNITS into its sub-units."
  (iter
    (with pos = (or (sub-units units) (list 0)))
    (for p in pos)
    (for last-p previous p)
    (for (head tail) first (split-at p units) then (split-at last-p tail))
    (when head
      (collect head into result))
    (finally (return (nconc result (list tail))))))
```

Is it possible to merge the two functions `sub-units` and `split-sub-units` into one? Does it make any difference regarding style or efficiency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem can be solved by iterating in the following way: collect all the elements in a list until their cdr are consecutive, and then repeat the previous process until the original list is empty, collecting all the produced lists. This can be done iteratively, with the total cost of *O(n)* where *n* is the length of the original list.

I use `loop` instead of `iterate` because I am more familiar with the first construct, it should be simple to convert it to iterate.

```
(defun split (l)
  (loop for (a b) = (loop for (x . y) on l
                          collect x into a
                          when (and y (/= (cdar y) (1+ (cdr x))))
                            do (return (list a y))   ; split here
                          finally (return (list a nil))) ; never split
        collect a        ; a list has been produced, collect it
        while b          ; if there are other elements
        do (setf l b)))  ; repeat splitting over them
```

A few tests:

```
CL-USER> (split '((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 2)))
(((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 2)))
CL-USER> (split '((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 3) (0 . 4) (0 . 7) (0 . 8)))
(((0 . 0) (0 . 1)) ((0 . 3) (0 . 4)) ((0 . 7) (0 . 8)))
CL-USER> (split '((0 . 0)))
(((0 . 0)))
CL-USER> (split '())
(NIL)
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn’t get this straight in my head. `Loop` is perfect here! I just started using `iterate` and am still practicing.